# How can i get a entity with sub entities in Entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-5, odata

i have a question about how to fill a json object to show a entity with sub entities.Thats because i have x that has got detail entity which is called y.

```
DbSyncScopeDescription scopeDesc = new DbSyncScopeDescription("filtered_customer");
```

// Definition for Customer.
DbSyncTableDescription customerDescription =
    SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable("Sales.Customer", serverConn);

scopeDesc.Tables.Add(customerDescription);

// Definition for CustomerContact, including the list of columns to include.
Collection columnsToInclude = new Collection();
columnsToInclude.Add("CustomerId");
columnsToInclude.Add("PhoneType");
DbSyncTableDescription customerContactDescription =
    SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable("Sales.CustomerContact", columnsToInclude, serverConn);

scopeDesc.Tables.Add(customerContactDescription);

Comment: Could you show your FavoriteStation mappings?

Comment: That's still not enough. Do you have mappings like HasRequired(t => t.Station).WithMany(t => t.FavoriteStations).HasForeignKey(d => d.StationId);?

Comment: Is LazyLoading disabled?

Comment: @BenitoBertoli : LazyLoading is disabled....

Comment: @VladimirSachek: No i dont have

Comment: @Penguen, you should override OnModelCreating method on your entities class RobbinsEntities and configure foreign keys

Comment: @BenitoBertoli this is not related to LazyLoading because Include method supposed to be used

Comment: @VladimirSachek you're right, I didn't notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two additional steps should be done:

1. Add EnableQuery attribute, or Queryable if not the latest version you are using:

   [EnableQuery]
    public static y x(Guid Id)
2. Add $expand to the query URL:

   /odata/2012-01/x(guid'xxxx')?$expand=t